# sencha touch geolocation get current position not working after 2-3 times on device (iphone 5)

Tags: javascript, geolocation, sencha-touch-2, cordova-3

I am trying to fetch the current location each time the user clicks a button.

```
 function checkConnection() {

  // check if there is connection and call the getcurrent position function
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onLocSuccess, onLocError);   

    }

    function onLocSuccess(position) {



                    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            //..........
            //..........
            // do something more
            //.....
        }
```

On the browser this works fine. But on the device (testing on iphone5), after 2-3 times of requesting, this piece of code does not fetch the location. It freezes, resulting in the app to freeze.

But interestingly, if i place an alert inside **onLocSuccess** it works fine !!!

```
    function onLocSuccess(position) {


            alert('this alert solves the issue');
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    //..........
    //..........
    // do something more
    //.....
}
```

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used **settimeout**. This works !

```
 function onLocSuccess(position) {


      setTimeout(function () {
          var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          //..........
          //..........
          // do something more
          //.....
      }, 50);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Home Button Implementation using Google map api v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom)

Comment: err... what is this ?

Comment: [Please don't post link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. I guess, there is some other issue behind the app freezing. Still you can try and check this once,

```
getCurrentLocation : function() {
        var me = this;
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                me.latitude = position.coords.latitude
                me.longitude =  position.coords.longitude;

                // User's location'
                me.position = new google.maps.LatLng(me.latitude, me.longitude);
            });
        } else {
            Ext.Msg.alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
        }  
    }
```